# How can I insert mathematical formulas into a markdown file with visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, math, markdown, visual-studio-code

I have used vscode to write markdown-file for several months, and it is a
perfect tool. 
But how can I insert **mathematical formulas** into a markdown file with Visual Studio Code? 
I can not find an effective solution by Google search. Does vscode support?

Comment: Visual Studio probably does _not_ support it. Related, a popular way to do it on the web and in wikis is to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). MathJax uses `<math>` tags which is rendered by the browser and produces expected markup/markdown.

Answer (score 5):

vscode v1.58 will have support for Katex:

---

#### Math formula rendering in the Markdown preview

VS Code's [built-in Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview) can now render math equations using [KaTeX](https://katex.org)

Inline math equations are wrapped in single dollar signs:

```
Inline math: $x^2$
```

While you can create a math equation block with double dollar signs:

```
Math block:

$$
\displaystyle
\left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right)^2
\leq
\left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \right)
\left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)
$$
```

You can set `"markdown.math.enabled": false` to disable this feature.

---

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#math-formula-rendering-in-the-markdown-preview

Comment: This is a great feature -- but I was surprised to learn KaTeX does not have built-in accessibility support.  NVDA on their home page, for example, doesn't see the rendered formula.  I prefer working directly w/TeX rather than porting to MathML, but I am surprised Microsoft overlooked its lack of accessibility support.  There doesn't seem to be an open threads on adding it, either.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown does not have a standard notation for mathematical formulas.

You can embed your formulas as images, and some formulas can be reasonably well approximated using Unicode. Furthermore, you can embed arbitrary tags, so you might conceivably be able to enter MathML. But some browsers, Chrome to mention an important one, don't support MathML and never will. Some sites like the Math Stack Exchange allow entering formulas to be rendered by MathJax. But that's non-standard Markdown as it disables Markdown semantics for the content of such equations.

Since there is no standard way to write formulas in Markdown, I'm not surprised if editors don't support editing it. After all, which of these various approaches should they follow?

If it's just a few formulas, I suggest you write them in LaTeX notation, feed them to KaTeX to turn them into statis HTML and then copy&paste that into your document. Of course, that process might conceivably be turned into an editor plugin. If someone knows of a plugin along these lines, they will sure write an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `Markdown+Math` extension in Code - works wonders in converting your equations in markdown using latex notation.