# vscode markdown preview not supporting some math commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, markdown

I'm writing markdown on vscode. But some math latex commands are not supported on vscode built-in preview. E.g.

```
$$ \ket{\psi} $$
```

cannot be properly rendered. How do I fix this? How do I add support to a bigger set of commands? Are there any extension that does this for me?

I installed `markdown + math` extension, but still not working for `\ket` command. Also for some reason, `markdown + math`'s official example for equation numbers supporting is not working. I don't understand why.

Comment: Better support is in v1.58 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68219948/836330 .  `$$ \ket{\psi} $$` and `$ \ket{\psi} $` both work for me in the INsiders Build now.

Answer (score 5):

[VSCode 1.58](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#math-formula-rendering-in-the-markdown-preview) (June 2021) will support math equations rendering in markdown:

> ### Math formula rendering in the Markdown preview
>
> VS Code's [built-in Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview) can now render math equations using [KaTeX](https://katex.org/)
>
> [image: Math rendering in the built-in markdown preview]
>
> Inline math equations are wrapped in single dollar signs:
>
> ```
> Inline math: $x^2$
> ```
>
> While you can create a math equation block with double dollar signs:
>
> ```latex
> Math block:
> $$
> \displaystyle
> \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right)^2
> \leq
> \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \right)
> \left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)
> $$
> ```
>
> You can set "markdown.math.enabled": false to disable this feature.

It even comes with:

> ### [Markdown math formula syntax highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#markdown-math-formula-syntax-highlighting)
>
> We now also support highlighting of math equations in Markdown source:
>
> [image: Syntax highlighting of a math equation in a markdown file]
>
> This works both in normal markdown files and in Markdown cells inside notebooks.